# My AWS CLI is not connecting to the localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am trying to set up DynamoDB on a local machine but didn't get progress. I have followed various tutorials even Amazon docs but didn't recognize where I am doing wrong.
[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3W5d.png)

Please guide me I would be very grateful. Thank You.

Comment: Did you read and follow the instructions at [Deploying DynamoDB Locally on Your Computer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)?

Comment: Yes, I followed each step but in the end, it throws above-mentioned error.

Comment: This is not a programming question and so is off-topic here. If you just delete it, you will get back the rep lost to downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to run the binary first

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Download binary from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html).

Comment: Already implemented but failed

Comment: Please check if the binary is running by hitting `ps -aux |grep java` command

Comment: no this command didn't execute

Comment: Something is wrong with your implementation then. Please follow the docs.